# How to programmatically publish asp.net web app using aspnet_compiler.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, publish, aspnet-compiler

I am learning how to automate the solution building, publishing, and deploying of ASP.NET websites. I am only using C# to execute cmd commands programatically, and I'm currently stuck with the publish process.

I have tried MSBuild but the output is not compiled the same as the `aspnet_compiler` files (dll is outside the bin folder and it creates an additional sub-folder). I recently noticed that VS used `aspnet_compiler.exe` in the publishing process but I don't know the backend process of how the `obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source` folder populates.

```
aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p "C:\Users\*SolutionPath*\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source" 
                    -u -c "C:\Users\*SolutionPath*\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir"
```

From my understanding this command I saw in the output box in VS is responsible for pre-compiling the files from the `Source` folder to `TempBuildDir` folder then it copies those files to your chosen publish file folder.

Comment: Visual Studio uses MSBuild. It is not two different build systems. Is your project .NET Framework or .NET? Aspnet_compiler.exe is .NET Framework only.